# Lookup a date, based on a variable, and then add a number of days to that date, to give a new date

Tags: excel

I am struggling to work out if this is an `If`, `countif`, `sumif` or `mixture`.

I would like to be able to find a date (1) that relates to a cell ( or number of cells) and then add a number of days to the date (1), to give me a new date (2).

**For example:**

A limit on overtime of no more than 1 lot of overtime in 10 days....

If the word "overtime" appears between A3-E3 (basic cells containing either "work","overtime", or "off", find the date that is correspondent to that date from A2-E2 (simply dates 1/2/2017  to  5/2/2017), then add 10 days to it to give me a date that the next lot of overtime can be started.

I have used `SUMIF` to find the date that the overtime occurs

`=SUMIF(A3:E3,"overtime",A2:E2)`

but can't follow the logic on to create a new date, 10 days later.

Thanks

xan21uk

Comment: datedif function with argument "D" for days? https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-datedif-function. An image of your data and desired output is also useful when posting a question

Comment: Hi, datedif gives me the days that are between 2 dates, but i want it to populate the date for me. Unless i am missing another way of entering the formula? which is quite possible. I can't add pics yet as i haven't posted 10 times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good candidate for `Index(Match())` style formula. `Index()` will return the value of a cell at a particular row and column in a range. `Match()` will find a particular value in a range and return it's position (whether row or column).

In your case, to add 5 days to the date where the next row contains the word "overtime":

```
=INDEX(A2:E2, 1, MATCH("*overtime*", A3:E3, 0)) + 5
```

The other tricky bit here is the use of wildcard characters. The asterisks `*` here allow us to match the term "overtime" anywhere in the cell's value. So even cells in the range `A3:E3` containing the value "This is a test for overtime searching" will cause a hit and return the column number.

Example:
[image]