# Formula to calculate a days pay depending on the date range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am working a sick leave pay schedule. The issue i am having is that we pay in 2 different ways; for every month , EXCEPT February, a days pay is worked out using ( in my sheet ):

```
B21/365*P28   (where B21 = annual salary and P28 = number of days)
```

However, i would like to create a formula that differentiates when a person was sick during February and pay the February days at a rate of

```
B21/12/28*P28
```

I assumed it would be a simple `if(and())` but i cannot get it work.

My dates of sick leave are added between `F28` ( start) `-G28` (end).

I would like it to know when a date is in Feb and count that many days at the Feb rate, and also count the other days at the normal rate.

As an example, if a person is ill between the 25th of January and 5th of February i'd like to pay 7 days at the normal rate, and 5 days at the February rate automatically. Cell `S28` is where the payment appears.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1 - Include Weekends**

I used this formula in `D2` (and drag down):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(MONTH(ROW(INDIRECT(A2&":"&B2)))=2)
```

[image]

And `E2` is simply:

```
=(B2-A2+1)-D2
```

---

**Option 2 - Exclude Weekends**

Use the following formulas:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((MONTH(ROW(INDIRECT(A2&":"&B2)))=2)*(WEEKDAY(ROW(INDIRECT(A2&":"&B2)),2)<=5))
```

and

```
=NETWORKDAYS(A2,B2)-D2
```

Comment: @ScottCraner, does this work? Always so fiddly working with dates like this!

Comment: I would have left both choices, as the OP did not specify, but as I see it this is correct.

Comment: @CallumDA looks good to me but for option 2 you don’t need -1 in NETWORKDAYS as it includes both start and end date anyway

Comment: @CallumDA I have this;                                 =MAX(0,MIN(IF($B2="",TODAY(),$B2),EOMONTH(DATEVALUE(C$1&"-17"),0))-MAX($A2,DATEVALUE(C$1&"-17"))+1)                                                                                         to count all the days that appear in the range above within a chose month, and year, but i'd like to be able to differentiate between the total days and workdays in that month of the year.

Comment: @xan21uk Option two above does just that

Comment: @CallumDA Sorry, it works perfectly until the date range goes over a year say 17-18, then it returns all the days in january within the range but doesn't differentiate between years.

Comment: @xan21uk - a couple of things: the comment sections aren't really the place for continued support. If this answers the question -- *as you asked it* -- then please accept the answer and also feel free to upvote it as a sign of gratitude. Whilst you're at it you should probably also accept [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46798023/2859347) on one of your other questions. If you try your best to adapt my answer to display the behaviour you now require over year-end and still don't manage then feel free to post a new question and I'm sure people will be more than willing to help :)

Comment: My apologies, I am new, and clearly have a lot to learn. Thanks for your help.